# Why do I need to use git-bash instead of cmd?

Tags: git-bash

I am using git in cmd(Command Prompt). But when I choose a course on [**GitHub Learning Lab**](https://stackoverflow.com) they recommend **git bash** for windows os. As I said, I am using cmd and why do I need to use **git bash** instead of cmd? Are there any benefits when I move to **git bash** this?

Comment: Because `bash` is far more flexible than `cmd` - and because it means that things like shell-scripts `.sh` can be reused with few changes between Linux, macOS, and Windows. When you use `cmd` and Windows batch files (`.bat` / `.cmd`) you'll find yourself constantly running into problems caused by CMD's own idiosyncrasies (e.g. it's _surprisingly difficult_ to do something like "move all files/folders to this other folder if they match this pattern"). Microsoft gave-up trying to fix CMD and instead invented PowerShell.

Comment: @Dai regarding `it's surprisingly difficult to do something like "move all files/folders to this other folder if they match this pattern"` can you expand? cmd syntax: `move a*b?cd.e target`. I think in Bash it's _surprisingly difficult_ to do something like "rename all files with extension a to have extension b". cmd: `ren *.a *.b`. Bash: `for i in (*.a); do mv ... err,... hmm... oh heck let's download the third-party utility "rename" instead`.

Comment: @k314159 Y'ever try to use `for` in CMD? Or `findstr` vs `find`? It's a thousand little things that just make it painful to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *need* to use Git Bash. It is just conventional, because Git was developed and designed on Linux and most Git users use Linux and using Git Bash on Windows makes it a uniform experience. You can certainly use Git on cmd; just make sure you add `C:\Program Files\git\cmd` to your `PATH`.

Comment: When you install Git for Windows, the installer will actually _recommend_ adding Git to your `PATH` so that you can use cmd and PowerShell. It will also add it for you if you select that option.